# How can I improve CPU utilization when using the multiprocessing module?

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I am working in Python 3.4, performing a naive search against partitioned data in memory, and am attempting to fork processes to take advantage of all available processing power.  I say naive, because I am certain there are other additional things that can be done to improve performance, but those potentials are out of scope for the question at hand.

The system I am testing on is a Windows 7 x64 environment.

What I would like to achieve is a relatively even, simultaneous distribution across `cpu_count() - 1` cores (reading suggests that distributing against all cores rather than n-1 cores does not show any additional improvement due to baseline os system processes). So 75% pegged cpu Usage for a 4 core machine.

What I am seeing (using windows task manager 'performance tab' and the 'process tab') is that **I never achieve greater than 25% system dedicated cpu utilization** and that the process view shows computation occurring one core at a time, switching every few seconds between the forked processes.

I haven't instrumented the code for timing, but I am pretty sure that my subjective observations are correct in that I am not gaining the performance increase I expected (3x on an i5 3320m).

I haven't tested on Linux.

Based on the code presented:
- How can I achieve 75% CPU utilization?

```
#pseudo code
def search_method(search_term, partition):
    <perform fuzzy search>
    return results

partitions = [<list of lists>]
search_terms = [<list of search terms>]

#real code
import multiprocessing as mp

pool = mp.Pool(processes=mp.cpu_count() - 1)

for search_term in search_terms:
    results = []
    results = [pool.apply(search_method, args=(search_term, partitions[x])) for x in range(len(partitions))]
```

Comment: You may want to know, that some `scikit-learn` functions have in-built options for going on multiple local-host cores. The point is, whether the solver computational strategy allows for non-intervening parallelised processing or not. The `multiprocessing` module has no clue whether it is possible to split the problem into more non-intervening parallel code-execution streams ( not speaking about data-access mechanics )

Comment: If your problem allows, there may be a more powerfull approach, to use a cloud of workers ( all based on python, distributed on multi-host, multi-CPU/multi-core infrastructure ), that can perform your `<_search_method_>` for a `<_search_term_>` on a given `<_list_of_lists_>`. Thus you may harness 10x, 100x, 1000x more CPU/core-s into such a privateCloud/Grid-engine tasking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're actually not doing anything concurrently here, because you're using `pool.apply`, which will block until the task you pass to it is complete. So, for every item in `partitions`, you're running `search_method` in some process inside of `pool`, waiting for it to complete, and then moving on to the next item. That perfectly coincides with what you're seeing in the Windows process manager. You want [`pool.apply_async`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.apply_async) instead:

```
for search_term in search_terms:
    results = []
    results = [pool.apply_async(search_method, args=(search_term, partitions[x])) for x in range(len(partitions))]

    # Get the actual results from the AsyncResult objects returned.
    results = [r.get() for r in results]
```

Or better yet, use [`pool.map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map) (along with [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to enable passing multiple arguments to our worker function):

```
from functools import partial
...

for search_term in search_terms:
    func = partial(search_method, search_term)
    results = pool.map(func, partitions)
```

Comment: this answers the specific question at hand. Thank you! I've been looking for an excuse to jump into cloud/grid computation and this may be the jumping off place...